# Print output of httpie command, then pipe to grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pipe, http

how can I print output of httpie request then pipe to grep to check if request has succeeded or failed?

`http --print=hb POST http://localhost:8080 | grep -c "HTTP/1.1 200" && echo "succeeded" && exit 0 || echo "failed" && exit 1`

I tried to use xargs with
`http://localhost:8080 | xargs sh -c 'response=$1' sh | grep ...`

but that didn't work, any idea

Comment: I wrote a general-purpose shell function for similar tasks: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1717757/432690). Maybe you can use/adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee` is the standard utility for sending a copy of stdin elsewhere.
`>()` is a bash construct that passes stdin into an arbitrary commmand.  Normally, we just pipe, '|' directly, but in our case where we want to send a copy of stdin on unaltered, this feature has some usage here.

Combine them, like so:

```
$ command1 | tee >( command2) | command3
```

`command2` and `command3` see the same thing

For your use case, try:

```
$ http --print=h http://www.google.com | tee >( grep -c "HTTP/1.1 200" >/dev/null && echo "succeeded" > /dev/stderr || echo "failed" > /dev/stderr) | sed 's/^/# /'
# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
# Date: Thu, 26 May 2022 00:32:29 GMT
... elided ...
# Set-Cookie: NID=511=CEilmSmMThJIS-KWlutGVDxrE; expires=Fri, 25-Nov-2022 00:32:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
# 
succeeded
```

I have `sed` as command3 to illustrate the contents it gets through the pipe -- a complete copy of `http`(ie)'s output.

Be careful!  `grep` wants to write to stdout by default (as do our `echo`es).  Thus, in command2, I redirect `grep`'s output to /dev/null, and the two `echo`es to /dev/error.  Without these, stdin is altered before `sed` begins its work.

Here's a snippet without command2's redirection:

```
$ http --print=h http://www.google.com | tee >( grep -c "HTTP/1.1 200" && echo "succeeded" || echo "failed") | sed 's/^/# /'
# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
# Date: Thu, 26 May 2022 00:35:01 GMT
... elided ...
# Set-Cookie: NID=511=L6sDnkpxBHQMA_L0JQCFqM; expires=Fri, 25-Nov-2022 00:35:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
# 
# 1
# succeeded
```

`sed` sees the `grep -c` count of one, and the `echo succeeded` -- it prepends '#'

Comment: thanks @Hefeweizen

Comment: I i'm sorry I forgot to mention that I need to exit with 0 in case of success and with 1 in case of failure, doing this with tee appears to exit only from tee not the whole script
I'll update my question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround

```
response=$(http --print=hb POST http://localhost:8080)
echo $response
echo $response | grep -c "HTTP/1.1 200" && echo "succeeded" || echo "failed")
```

Comment: I have a (fun|convoluted) answer below.  Do this, it's more readable.  One step more would be to drop the short-circuits, and write a shell if block.  short-circuits and conveniences are great for getting something working on the command line, but for maintainable solutions (such as scripts) write for clarity.

Comment: @Hefeweizen Side note: there is no fixed order of answers, so your "below" is meaningless or even misleading. E.g. at this moment I can see your answer *above*.